# Laravel validate rule

Tags: laravel, validation

I have two datepicker input fields: `from` and `to`. To ensure that field value `to` is greater than field value `from`, I use the `after` validation rule. Everything is fine up until I leave the `from` input value null. Because I am applying the validation rule using the input value `from`.
How can I combine the `required` and `after` validation rules without running into this problem?

```
$from = $request->input('from');
$from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i', $from)->format('Y-m-d H:i A');
$attributes= request()->validate([
       'from' => 'required|date',
       'to'=> 'nullable|date|after:'.$from,
]);
```

Data missing error while `from` input value is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laravel validation rule allows you to compare a field against another field. So you can simply add: `after:from`
See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-after) here.

```
$attributes = request()->validate([
    'from' => 'required|date',
    'to'=> 'nullable|date|after:from',
]);
```

Comment: I'm wondering how I'm not familiar with that simple solution.